# angular 2 externalised properties

Tags: angular

I'm new to the world of **angular 2**, with a java/groovy background.

I'm trying to understand the mechanism for **property interpolation**, my setup is using `webpack` for packaging and Typescript for dev, I'm struggling to see any viable option.

**Java/Groovy example**

For instance a `Spring Boot` project using `Gradle`/`Maven` would have `application.properties` or `application.yml` with placeholders and then **different phases** and properties values for each... e.g. `dev, test, prod`. The idea being you would require a different url properties for a mocked dev url and another for the real production version in prod phase, etc.

**Process**

- build process with node using webpack (transcompile, etc)
- pass to some form of property template to interpolate different values
- (OPTIONAL) be able to override with cmd line args